# Select all posts created by all users a given user follows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to obtain all posts created by all users a given user follows.

Tables: posts, users, followers

### Users

```
id int(255)
```

Which is associated with:

### Followers

```
id int(255)
user_id int(255) //The id of person that's is following
following int(255) //The id of person being followed
```

Which is also associated with:

### Posts

```
id int(255)
user_id(255) //The id of person who created the post
```

I don't know what is needed here to achieve this in a single query. Normally, I would obtain all users the user follows and then loop through all users obtaining the posts of each. Using this approach, my results are first sorted by user, then sorted by date. I want to sort all posts by date.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple join should suffice. The `?` is where the user id of the 'follower' goes.

```
SELECT * FROM Posts p
INNER JOIN Followers f ON (f.following = p.user_id)
WHERE f.user_id = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this queries you just have to join multiple tables

```
    SELECT P.*
      FROM users     U
INNER JOIN followers F ON (F.user_id = U.id)
INNER JOIN users    FU ON (FU.id = F.following)
INNER JOIN posts     P ON(P.user_id = F.id)
     WHERE U.id = :id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT posts.id as post_id
FROM users
JOIN followers ON followers.user_id = users.id
JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = followers.following
WHERE users.user_id = ?
```

All you need is to join the 3 tables. Join `users` to `followers` and then join `followers` to `posts`.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 0):

the followers table has the id of the user you are looking at so there is no need to join to the users table specifically if you are only looking at posts.
Also, note I have used a derived table to filter the results early so that we are only getting those records from the posts table we are interested in... if we filter in the outer query we have to get everything from what could be large tables and then apply the filter... i.e. this is one way you could improve the performance of the query.

```
select p.*
from 
    (select following from followers where user_id = @your_user) f
    inner join posts p
        on p.user_id = f.following
order by p.date
```

Although you don't specify it, my query assumes the date column is in the posts table. I also am interpreting what you have stated in the question as you are wanting to sort by date only.